# Putting multiple data in same zip entry

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zip

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream);

private void addToS3(List<Data> data) throws IOException {
try {
    zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("abc.csv"));

    for (Data item : data) {
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(item.getBytes());
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

        StringBuilder csvContent = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            csvContent.append(line).append("\n");
        }

        zipOutputStream.write(csvContent.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        bufferedReader.close();

        if (outputStream.size() > 5 * 1024 * 1024) {
            uploadToS3ByPart(new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray()), false);
            outputStream.reset();
        }
    }

    zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
} finally {
    zipOutputStream.close();
}

uploadToS3ByPart(new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray()), true);
}
```

This is the code I'm working on, after writing bytes to zipoutputstream, it's not reflecting on outputstream so size remains default 37 even after writing multiple item. The data written reflects only ofter I close zip entry but if I do that I'll not be able to write the next item to same file. So please let me know if you have any idea

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have updated the question, with more details.please have a look